# AccessDataSource control reports unrecognizable database

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, ms-access-2007, visual-web-developer

I am running visual studio 2012 express for the web and on the page I added an asp dropdown box. I tried to load the source from an access 2007 database using an asp:AccessDataSource object. The wizzard completed fine. when I ran the page in the web, I got am error message telling me that the database was in an unrecognisable format. I googled the problem and found out the visual studio does not know to use the provider Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0  and that I would need to modify the connection string.

Since I'm not writing the code for this page, and relying on VS's visual interface to generate the code, how do I find the code to modify it? Or do I simply write my own code and not rely on VS to do it for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sample code on the page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.accessdatasource.connectionstring.aspx) to display the connection string that your AccessDataSource is using. Verify that the connection string includes

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
```

and the path to the `Data source` is valid.

FWIW, I just tried to recreate your issue under Visual Web Developer 2010 Express with an Access 2010 database and it worked just fine for me. I also couldn't find any evidence that the connection string for the AccessDataSource was actually "written down" anywhere, in `Web.config` or elsewhere.

Comment: i started with Visual Web Developer 2010 Express and couldn't get it to understand the format of an access 2007 DB. that's why I upgraded to 2012 and still no go. the weird thing is that VS can show expected output in the data source wizzard but in web it complains about the DB format. I even downgraded the DB from access 2010 to 2007 which did not help.

Comment: @user1617356 That's odd, because I didn't have to do anything special to make my test case work, but then **(1)** My test box was 32-bit Windows Server 2003, **(2)** It had Office 2010 as well as VWD Express 2010. It *might* be a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue, but that's just a guess. Does your connection string look valid at runtime?

Comment: Ok. I was recently upgraded to a win 7 64bit box. I have office 2007 and VD 2012.

For the first few pages I wrote the code directly and was able to get everything working. I then wanted to take advantage of VS's ASP objects on another form so I could try generating input validation without writing the javascript. That's where I noticed the problem. Worst part is that all I have to deal with is the ASP object which hides any code.

Maybe it is a 64 bit issue, but I tend to doubt it as I would have seen more posts about this. 64 bit opperating systems have been around a few years now.

Comment: I just reread my earlier post and I'm more confused. The wizzard in VS asks me to select the mdb file but my DB is accdb. the cool thing is that VS can show output before saving the asp:datasource object. But when I run the page in IE, I get the message: "Unrecognized database format 'C:\Users\itweb\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Notitiae_Project\Notitiae_Project\App_Data\notitiae.accdb'"

Comment: @user1617356 There are actually quite a lot of posts (here and elsewhere) about 32-bit vs. 64-bit versions of the Access Database Engine (ACE). Say, for example, that you have the 32-bit version of Visual Web Developer and the AccessDataSource setup wizard uses the 32-bit ACE drivers, and they work. Then, when you run the page under IIS then ASP.NET may run in the 64-bit "world" for which no 64-bit drivers are available. (64-bit ACE components cannot be installed on a machine that already has 32-bit Office applications installed.) That's just one example.

Comment: I know IIS on my dev machin is setup to support 32 bit applications, my office products are 32 bit and the OS is 64 bit.

Eventually the host for the code will be a 64 bit sharepoint server. does any of this matter if IIS is set to support 32 bit applications?

Comment: @user1617356 RE: "How do I get all of this to work?" That's the $64 (or maybe $32) question, isn't it? You still haven't shown us the connection string that the AccessDataSource is *actually using* (see my answer). If it is trying to use Jet.OLEDB then that would explain the "Unrecognized database format" error. However, we need to *confirm* things like that before we go chasing down false leads. And, as you said in your question, if the AccessDataSource turns out to be too much of a nuisance you can always "simply write [your] own code and not rely on VS to do it for [you]".

Comment: I can't get the connection string. All I get is a message that the database in an unrecognized format. The page fails to execute beyond that and to process my request for the connection string.

I may need to code this as the connection string I need to use is: "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=C:\Users\itweb\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Notitiae_project\Notitiae_project\App_Data\notitiae.accdb;" & "Jet OLEDB:System Database=V:\DATABASE\WORKDIR\diodb.mdw;" & "User ID=ITWeb;" & "Password=Mike1;"

Comment: so...do you think upgrading my office products to 64 bit ad loading the 64 bit Access Database engine will solve my problem? at the moment I'm building on a 64 bit win 7 box. eventually I will move to a 64 bit SharePoint server .

Comment: As you said in you answer, I think this is a moot point now that you have to connect to an `.mdb` file that has user-level security enabled.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog entry](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/78/AccessDataSource-SqlDataSource-and-connecting-to-Access-databases-in-ASP.NET):

> AccessDataSource control
>
> The more I consider it, the more pointless this control seems to me. The only good thing about it is that it works. However, it only works for the .mdb format, as it invokes the Jet Provider internally, and this cannot be changed. You cannot use it with password protected file, as it automatically generates the Connection string from the location of the .mdb file, which you feed to the DataFile property

Thus I will either have to work with an .mdb file or generate the code manually. I vote for the manual creation.

Comment: I agree that the AccessDataSource control will probably not work for you now that you need to connect to an `.mdb` file that has user-level security enabled. However, as I said in my answer, it *can* work with an `.accdb` file; I did it myself.